# Any difference or similarity between href and routerLink in Angular

Tags: html, angular

This is my navbar.html

```
<ul class="white">
      <li><a href="/signup">Signup</a></li>
      <li><a href="/challange">Create Challange</a></li>
      <li><a href="/feed">News Feed</a></li>
    </ul>
```

This is my app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Click on an each menu link its feel as loading an entire page even i run this code in localhost. But, I seen many angular project page is not loading entirely just change that url only.

My question, this problem is arrive from `href`? 
shall I use `roouterLink` to overcome this issue?

Comment: You should always use routerLink if you are using the Angular built in router as it's best practices and I'm sure there's plenty of behind the scene benefits

Comment: Can u please elaborate

Comment: Sorry I'm typing on my mobile and it is a bit difficult. But one example is in routerLink you can easily navigate to a parent component or go up 2 levels in the routing by doing '../' or '../../' which you can't do in href.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried Its working fine. Before It was loading an entire page, Now it's working

Comment: it might be worth noting that sometimes it actually reloads the whole page when there is an error. because the application sometimes reloads it can clear out the console output, so it might be worth ticking the box which lets you persist your console output

Comment: You can check my answer for a detailed overview:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632191/8389728

Answer (score 2):

**routerLink:**

- It is a directive in angular2+
- Navigates to New Url and the component is rendered in place of routeroutlet without reloading the page

**href:**

- Its an attribute of a tag
- html anchor tag attribute to navigate to another page and reload the entire app

Answer (score -1):

In angular you can define different `states` and then route to/render those states (using `ui-sref` as compared to `href` in simple `html`) without reloading page. Only `url` gets changes. Read more about `ui-router` [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference) and [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)

Check this [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7?p=preview) for demo code

Comment: No, It's not angular4. It's angularjs 1

Comment: yeah it's angular. so what ?

Comment: concept is the same

Comment: Difference is with the routerLink you can pass I  route parameter object which can be really useful if you are using a ngFor